# Python Access Denied When Renaming A File

Tags: python

I am working on a project for school to rename some files and create and do things with files. Some of the files are in the C drive and I need to get around:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
     os.rename('C:\Windows\System32\C_950.NLS' , 'C:\Windows\System32\C_950.NLS')
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

The Files are just an example I will be changing my own files. I have admin control on the computer however I need a way to give it to my friend who does not have admin control. Is there any semi-cheaty way to get around this? Also is there a way to send commands to command prompt through python?

Comment: Are you changing the name at all?  Looks the same to me.  Windows probably doesn't want you touching those files.

Comment: You can't move system files without administrator privileges; no way around that within Python. If the error happens for you, too: are you running the script as an administrator? Administrator privileges don't cut it.

Comment: I updated the the question a bit. So is there anyway to edit system files from a nonAdmin propgram?

Comment: There's no way to get around access permissions.  That's not a language issue, it's an OS issue.  The runtime still needs to go through the kernel to get access to those files.

Comment: The slashes should be entered forward-slashes so that Python doesn't interpret the backward-slashes as escape sequences, e.g. 'C:\temp\name.txt' would interpret the `\t` as a tab and `\n` as a new-line.

Comment: Can I rename system files in a C variation?

Comment: @JoshBode I don't think that would be the case (backslash), python would read file even there is backslash or forwordslash in filename.
As the Error statement made it quite precise `Access Denied`.
@minitech & @Haz's comments are good enough as an answer to the OP.

Comment: @RahulGautam True, Python can read files with a forward-/back-slash in the name (though windows might take exception at you naming a file with a back-slash) but to _refer_ to the filename from Python you need to be careful with back-slash escaping. As an alternative, you could just use a raw string (e.g. r'C:\temp\name.txt') and Python will not interpret the escapes.

Comment: I am using python 3.2 and I think that the backslash escape character issue you guys are talking about is for 2.7. Some of my classmates were talking about it. I don't really remember the outcome.

Comment: yeah that's also true @JoshBode. Alex its the case < 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not answering the main question, but to execute commands on the system, you can use `os.system`, e.g.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('net use')
```

Comment: I need to run "net user test /add" how can i run admin commands? or can i not in python?

Comment: Not on Windows at home to test this, but I believe you could either run python as admin (not great) or use [runas](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) to elevate your permissions (similar to `sudo` on *nix), e.g. `os.system('runas /user:DOMAIN\\USERNAME "net user test /add"')`

Comment: ok that should work great. Thanks! Also is there any way to just pipe the command and not open a cmd window?

Comment: @AlexPelletier you should look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, specifically the `subprocess.Popen` command for this (`os.system` is only suitable for very basic usage)